# HTML CSS: Is there a Useless tag which does nothing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to create a useless Html Tag which does not do anything (does not affect formatting, content, spacing, more like a empty label? Is it span or div?

I want to place a useless tag around the following items. If I add span or div before and after, it shifts the items up in Codepen. Looking only for one tag container, not two.

https://codepen.io/WebTesting41/pen/YoBmye

```
 <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">notifications</i>
 <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">delete</i>
```

**Code:**

```
.grid-container 
{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 50px);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px);
 grid-gap: 1px;
 padding: 0px;
 align-items: center;
}
  
.material-icons
{
   text-align:center;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="grid-container" id="gridid1556351f5ece4ee3a7dce6962be48e39" >
   <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">notifications</i>
   <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">delete</i>
</div>
```

Comment: you named them, span and div are neutral tags, one is inline to hold text, the other is block to hold any tags. your might be looking for span, but white space in html are seen at screen, else words would glue to each others.

Comment: span and div kept shifting all items everything up in codepen

Comment: what do you  mean by up?

Comment: https://codepen.io/WebTesting41/pen/YoBmye

Comment: not sure why question is voted down, seems like valid question, attached codepen, thanks

Comment: add `span {margin:auto;}` and it should be fine again

Comment: ok, seems like there isnt useless tag, may always requires a css custom, thanks anyway,

Comment: semanticly neutral, but useless not. I do not understand what you mean by useless if you want to add an extra wrapper, there's got to be a use somehow ? if you wrap <i> tags, then they are no more grid children, the span is and that makes a single row, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  for both elements separately. You used one span for both elements in codepen. I've edited the html file. Check it. Hope it will help you.

```css
.grid-container.toolsetbutton
{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 50px);
/*  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px); */
 grid-gap: 1px;
 padding: 0px;
 align-items: center;
}
  
.material-icons.toolsetbutton
{
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="grid-container toolsetbutton" id="gridid1556351f5ece4ee3a7dce6962be48e39" >
   <span><i class="material-icons toolsetbutton" style="font-size:48px;">notifications</i>
   <i class="material-icons toolsetbutton" style="font-size:48px;">delete</i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: looking only for one container, not two

Comment: @jerrythomas I've edited the code. I just comment out "grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px); " property in css. Check it.

Comment: dont want to affect css editing, just looking for simple html tag, seems like html tag does not support useless labels, always have to edit css

Comment: is it ok if I use a css property for the span? @jerrythomas

Comment: If it is ok then add "span { margin-top: 50px; }" in your css. @jerrythomas