# Conditionally insert a row in HTML table (Angular)

Tags: html, angularjs, node-red

### Question

How can I conditionally insert a row in an HTML table using Angular?

### A bit more detail about the problem

I'm working with Angular in Node-RED, here's my table which walks through each key / value in an object:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in msg.shellies">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{value.up_since_time}} {{value.up_since_date}})</td>
        <td>{{value.data}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know how to conditionally add any element, e.g. `<span>` like so:

```
<span ng-if="value.state === 'up'">The device is UP</span>
```

But clearly I cannot wrap a table row in a `<span>` (HTML would not validate) and I want the ng-repeat to apply to the table row.

### Initial thought

My initial thought was that there must be some HTML element that gets ignored by the browser, and I could apply the `ng-repeat` to that element, applying `ng-if` to the table row. e.g.

```
<magic_invisible_tag ng-repeat="(key, value) in msg.shellies">
    <tr ng-if="value.state === 'up'">
        <td>.....</td>
    </tr>
</magic_invisible_tag>
```

But that's clearly not possible having read [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897305/html-tag-safe-for-enclosing-elements-that-does-nothing) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56995609/html-css-is-there-a-useless-tag-which-does-nothing) on Stack Overflow.

Is there some other notation that works in Angular for this?

Answer (score 0):

Having tried this, it appears it's possible to just ad the ng-if directive to the table row itself.

I guess Angular does the work already to somehow ensure the ng-repeat directive works regardless of the ng-if directive in the same element.